# PostgreSQL asks for password when I add "-h" parameter to psql?

Tags: postgresql

I have an installed PostgreSQL database on my Ubuntu and I want to use `psql` to execute queries in it.
Normally when I use it in the following format, it works fine:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "<the query>"
<query response without asking for password>
```

But when I add the `-h 127.0.01` parameters, it asks for password as below:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u postgres psql -h "127.0.0.1" -c "<the query>"
password:I
```

The question is why? What is the difference? In both cases I am connecting to the same database. How can I prevent asking password?

[image]

Comment: One is through a TCP connection and one is connecting through a local socket file. When you go through TCP, postgres has no way to know what your current user is.

Comment: So, what can I do? Postgres default user has no password I guess, right? So how can I authenticate myself through the TCP connection to create a new user and assign it a password?

Comment: Your pg_hba.conf is configured to demand a password for "host", but not for "local".  You have many options.  Change pg_hba.conf, or don't use -h, or use -h but with a socket directory rather than a host, or assign a password and use it.  You don't need to use a TCP connection to create a new user.